# Problem referencing classes in external assembly in WPF designer in VS 2008?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2008

Here, Data refers to a another class-library project in the same solution. The main project is referencing Data properly and there is a data.dll in the debug directory of the main project. Yes, I am able to build and run this solution properly.

Is this a known problem? I searched on the web, but am unable to find a definite answer.

[Problem referencing classes in external assembly in WPF designer in VS 2008? http://img200.imageshack.us/img200/1087/bghelpertext.jpg](http://img200.imageshack.us/img200/1087/bghelpertext.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's a [well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926625/why-would-my-xaml-editor-be-giving-me-an-error-but-the-project-compiles-and-runs) [known](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/647726/how-to-solve-xaml-designer-error-the-document-contains-errors-that-must-be-fixed) problem.